data wrangling help in assigning items across lists using dplyr
have a dataset containing items to be used in a psychology experiment. Counterbalancing is crucial for this experiment. I need to arrange the items across 4 lists. I would appreciate your help in achieving two goals:

I need to input the Items col, with numbers in order to identify all Items sharing the same W2. For this to be done properly, it must follow 2 options:
A) Any phrase containing the same W1 or W2 should be assigned the same unique number.
B) Items from the condition (Non_Word) must be assigned the same Items number as the Item above it (e.g., if the phrase above it is assigned the number 1, it needs to match that number).

I need to arrange all Items across 4 lists (the col List). Arranging them into lists needs to follow these two conditions: A) Items with the same unique number (except Non_Word) must not be in the same list; B) Items from the condition Non_Word must be assigned the same List number as the Item above it (i.e., participants need to see both Word and non-word control)


Below is a sample of the original data.
 dput(sample_1)
structure(list(Phrase = c("fresh start", "rapid clett", "recent start", 
"bright shuce", "near future", "dark stealt", "next future", 
"blue brerps", "start fresh", "good sdfjj", "start recent", "bad fsdh", 
"future near", "blue ndsd", "future next", "white dss"), Items = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    W1 = c("fresh", "rapid", "recent", "bright", "near", "dark", 
    "next", "blue", "start", "start", "start", "bad", "future", 
    "blue", "future", "white"), W2 = c("start", "clett", "start", 
    "shuce", "future", "stealt", "future", "brerps", "fresh", 
    "sdfjj", "recent", "fsdh", "near", "ndsd", "next", "dss"), 
    Condition = c("Incong", "Non_Word", "Control", "Non_Word", 
    "Cong", "Non_Word", "Control", "Non_Word", "Incong", "Non_Word", 
    "Control", "Non_Word", "Cong", "Non_Word", "Control", "Non_Word"
    ), Direction = c("Fw_Incong", "Fw_NW", "Fw_Control", "Fw_NW", 
    "Fw_Cong", "Fw_NW", "Fw_Control", "Fw_NW", "Back_Incong", 
    "Back_NW", "Back_Control", "Back_NW", "Back_Cong", "Back_NW", 
    "Back_Control", "Back_NW"), List = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))

Below is the desired sample data.
dput(sample_2)
structure(list(Phrase = c("fresh start", "rapid clett", "recent start", 
"bright shuce", "near future", "dark stealt", "next future", 
"blue brerps", "start fresh", "good sdfjj", "start recent", "bad fsdh", 
"future near", "blue ndsd", "future next", "white dss"), Items = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), W1 = c("fresh", 
"rapid", "recent", "bright", "near", "dark", "next", "blue", 
"start", "start", "start", "bad", "future", "blue", "future", 
"white"), W2 = c("start", "clett", "start", "shuce", "future", 
"stealt", "future", "brerps", "fresh", "sdfjj", "recent", "fsdh", 
"near", "ndsd", "next", "dss"), Condition = c("Incong", "Non_Word", 
"Control", "Non_Word", "Cong", "Non_Word", "Control", "Non_Word", 
"Incong", "Non_Word", "Control", "Non_Word", "Cong", "Non_Word", 
"Control", "Non_Word"), Direction = c("Fw_Incong", "Fw_NW", "Fw_Control", 
"Fw_NW", "Fw_Cong", "Fw_NW", "Fw_Control", "Fw_NW", "Back_Incong", 
"Back_NW", "Back_Control", "Back_NW", "Back_Cong", "Back_NW", 
"Back_Control", "Back_NW"), List = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -16L))

Here is what I did:
# Step 1: Assign unique item numbers based on W1 or W2 and Non_Word rules
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Items = NA_integer_) %>%  # Initialize the Items column
  group_by(W1, W2) %>%
  mutate(Items = cur_group_id()) %>%  # Assign unique IDs based on W1 or W2
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Items = ifelse(Condition == "Non_Word", lag(Items, default = first(Items)), Items))  # Adjust for Non_Word

# Step 2: Assign items to 4 lists under the constraints
data <- data %>%
  arrange(Items, Condition != "Non_Word") %>%  # Ensure data is sorted by Items, prioritizing non-Non_Word items
  group_by(Items) %>%
  mutate(List = rep(1:4, length.out = n())) %>%  # Distribute Items across 4 lists
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Items) %>%
  mutate(
    List = ifelse(
      Condition == "Non_Word", lag(List, default = first(List)), List
    ),  # Adjust Non_Word to match the list of the preceding item
    List = ifelse(duplicated(List) & Condition != "Non_Word", NA, List)  # Ensure no duplicates for same Items (non-Non_Word)
  ) %>%
  fill(List, .direction = "down") %>%  # Fill missing lists downward
  ungroup()


However, the code only succeeded in ensuring items of "Non_Word" match items above them in List and Item number. However, the other goals were not achieved.

This is an interesting task; I think I found a way to achieve the first goal (although it is a bit convoluted and there must be easier ways), but I am not sure I understand the second goal: I get that  Items with the same unique number (except Non_Word) must not be in the same list, but what ar the reasons for two items to be in the same list (except for Non_word)? Why are row 1 and row 15 both in List 1?? I will be happy to send the code after I get this
